# How to use downloadContentForTransaction: success: progress: failure: in RMStore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I'm trying to use this method from [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore)

```
- (void)downloadContentForTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction
                              success:(void (^)())successBlock
                             progress:(void (^)(float progress))progressBlock
                              failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;
```

but I don't understand how to use it. Can anyone show me an example?

**Update:**

When I select method from autocomplete list, it don't create blocks automatically
[image]
like usual:
 [image]
When I try to open it manually I got errors
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the RMStore [readme](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/master/README.md):

> RMStore delegates the downloading of self-hosted content via the
>   optional `contentDownloader` delegate. You can provide your own
>   implementation using the `RMStoreContentDownloader` protocol.

In short, `downloadContentForTransaction:success:progress:failure:` is part of a protocol you need to implement, not call.

I should add that if you're using Apple hosted content, RMStore will take care of it automatically. Again, from the readme:

> Downloadable content hosted by Apple (`SKDownload`) will be
>   automatically downloaded when purchasing o restoring a product.
>   RMStore will notify observers of the download progress by calling
>   `storeDownloadUpdate:` and finally `storeDownloadFinished:`. Additionally,
>   RMStore notifies when downloads are paused, cancelled or have failed.
>
> RMStore will notify that a transaction finished or failed only after
>   all of its downloads have been processed. If you use blocks, they will
>   called afterwards as well. The same applies to restoring transactions.